# How to netcat multiple files without tar?

Tags: tar, file-transfer, netcat

Currently I am transporting files back and forth over telnet and I would like to send multiple files at once.

However, my target platform (a Blackfin processor) does not have "tar" enabled in its kernel/busybox configuration (a uClinux distribution).

As you all know the normal command is:

```
nc -p 12345 -l | tar -x
tar -c * | nc 192.168.0.100 12345 # with x.100 the robot IP address
```

How can I send multiple files using netcat **without using tar**?

Please, consider that I cannot easily add binaries on the platform. It would be best to do it with basic utilities and/or shell scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally managed myself to do this, it can be done!

Here `$l>` stands for your machine with `IP 192.168.0.10`. And `$e>` is done on the embedded device without tar, in my case a robot. It uses old-fashioned `dd` which is able to copy an entire disk.

```
$l> nc -p 12345 -l | dd obs=4K of=/tmp/file.jffs2
$e> dd ibs=4K if=/dev/mtdblock2 | nc 192.168.0.10 12345
```

This is it, but because not everybody knows how to read a filesystem that is in this form, this is how you mount it:

```
file /tmp/file.jffs2
  /tmp/file.jffs2: Linux jffs2 filesystem data little endian
sudo su     #careful
mknod /tmp/mtdblock0 b 31 0
modprobe loop
losetup /dev/loop0 /tmp/file.jffs2
modprobe mtdblock
modprobe block2mtd
echo "/dev/loop0,128KiB" > /sys/module/block2mtd/parameters/block2mtd
modprobe jffs2
mkdir /media/robot
mount -t jffs2 /tmp/mtdblock0 /media/robot
Ctrl-D  #back as normal user
```

And yes, you need the loopback device, or else:

```
sudo mount -t jffs2 /tmp/file.jffs2 /media/robot
  mount: /tmp/file.jffs2 is not a block device (maybe try `-o loop'?)
```

Logically, it is a file (chars), and not a block device. The only thing I do not know is if there is a syntax for `dd` in which the command on the embedded device, can only select a subset of the filesystem to be included. I don't think this is likely because that would require `dd` to understand `jffs2` while its strength is its raw byte copying behaviour.